# Python: matching OR of two variables containing regex code

Tags: python, regex

What I am trying to do is to take user input text which would contain wildcards (so I need to keep them that way) but furthermore to look for the specified input.  So for example that I have working below I use the pipe |.

I figured out how to make this work:

```
dual = 'a bunch of stuff and a bunch more stuff!'
reobj = re.compile('b(.*?)f|\s[a](.*?)u', re.IGNORECASE)
result = reobj.findall(dual)
for link in result:
        print link[0] +'    ' + link[1]
```

which returns:

unch o
       nd a b

As well

```
dual2 = 'a bunch of stuff and a bunch more stuff!'
#So I want to now send in the regex codes of my own.
userin1 = 'b(.*?)f' 
userin2 = '\s[a](.*?)u'
reobj = re.compile(userin1, re.IGNORECASE)
result = reobj.findall(dual2)
for link in result:
        print link[0] +'    ' + link[1]
```

Which returns:

u        n 
u        n

I don't understand what it is doing as if I get rid of all save link[0] in print I get: 
u 
u

I however can pass in a user input regex string:

```
dual = 'a bunch of stuff and a bunch more stuff!'
userinput = 'b(.*?)f'
reobj = re.compile(userinput, re.IGNORECASE)
result = reobj.findall(dual)
print(result)
```

but when I try to update this to two user strings with the pipe:

```
dual = 'a bunch of stuff and a bunch more stuff!'
userin1 = 'b(.*?)f' 
userin2 = '\s[a](.*?)u'
reobj = re.compile(userin1|userin2, re.IGNORECASE)
result = reobj.findall(dual)
print(result)
```

I get the error:

reobj = re.compile(userin1|userin2, re.IGNORECASE)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

I get this error a lot such as if I put brackets () or [] around userin1|userin2.

I have found the following:

[Python regular expressions OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609597/python-regular-expressions-or)

but can not get it to work ;..{-( .

What I would like to do is to be able to understand how to pass in these regex variables such as that of OR and return all the matches of both as well as something such as AND - which in the end is useful as it will operate on files and let me know which files contain particular words with the various logical relations OR, AND etc.

Thanks much for your thoughts,

Brian

Comment: You have to use the pipe as a string, rather than an operator. Think: "a|b" rather than "a" | "b"

Answer (score 1):

Although I couldn't get the answer from A. Rodas to work, he gave the idea for the .join.  The example I worked out - although slightly different returns (in link[0] and link[1]) the desired results.

```
userin1 = '(T.*?n)'
userin2 = '(G.*?p)'
list_patterns = [userin1,userin2]
swaplogic = '|'
string = 'What is a Torsion Abelian Group (TAB)?'
theresult = re.findall(swaplogic.join(list_patterns), string)
print theresult
for link in theresult:
        print link[0]+'  '+link[1]
```