# Python regex findall OR

Tags: python, regex

I am compiling the following pattern:

```
pattern = re.compile("media.+\.(aac|ts)")
```

My idea is to obtain .ts and .aac media files contained in a string.
The media file names can be media-u9xuxtkay_213.aac or media-u9xuxtkay_213.ts

According to this accepted answer [Python regular expressions OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609597/python-regular-expressions-or) you can use ( | ) as an OR
But I dont see how that's an accepted answer since it doenst seem to work to me:

```
In [23]: s
Out[23]: 'Sent from my iPhone'

In [24]: patt = re.compile("Sent from my (iPhone|iPod)")

In [25]: patt.findall(s)
Out[25]: ['iPhone']
```

So I call the findall and I get this:

```
In [37]: media
Out[37]: 'media-u9xuxtkay_213.aac'

In [38]: pattern = re.compile("media.+\.(aac|ts)")

In [39]: pattern.findall(media)
Out[39]: ['aac']
```

I should get a media-u9xuxtkay_213.aac instead just aac. The same way the accepted answer should return Sent from my iPhone instead just iPhone

Comment: Use `r"media.+\.(?:aac|ts)"`, a non-capturing group.

Comment: So the accepted answer in the other question is wrong?

Comment: No,  if you use it with `re.finditer` and grab `.group()`. But there is a more convenient thing - a non-capturing group.

Comment: Might be duplicated but the question you linked is impossible to find through the search engine with that title when looking for this issue.

Comment: I found it with "re.findall wierd behavior" - top result. It is becoming a very frequent, repetitive issue. BTW, what search words did you use?

Comment: typed the same thing, doesnt even appear in the first page, but "ok"

Comment: I looked for "python regex or" to see how to use it properly and the first question it's a wrong one which is not doing what OP asked and still is accepted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609597/python-regular-expressions-or

Comment: The question I linked has 19k views, the one you linked  has barely 200, so guess where the search engine are leading to

Comment: Well, the second answer in the thread you linked to provides the regex compatible with re.findall. So, it can also be used to close this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parentheses act as a "capture group", denoting what the regex should select from the string.  You can use [`(?: )`](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) to make it a non-capturing group, so it gets the whole string instead.

```
re.compile(r"media.+\.(?:aac|ts)")
```