# How to do regular expressions with OR

Tags: python

Had two inputs based on the device it need to match any of input using Or and give the version output like 7.0.3I4.6 or 7.1.4.N1.1

Input-1
NXOS image file is: bootflash:///nxos.7.0.3.I4.6.bin

Input-2
kickstart image file is: bootflash:///n6000-uk9-kickstart.7.1.4.N1.1.bin
system image file is:    bootflash:///n6000-uk9.7.1.4.N1.1.bin

Please suggest how to filter using Or and regular expression

Tried

```
regex_version = re.compile(r'(NXOS:\sversion\s(\S+))|(kickstart:\sversion\s(\S+))')

version = regex_version.findall(input)
```

---

Tried

```
regex_version = re.compile(r'(NXOS:\sversion\s(\S+))|(kickstart:\sversion\s(\S+))')

version = regex_version.findall(input)
```

output:
[('NXOS: version 7.0(3)I4(6)', '7.0(3)I4(6)', '', '')]
[('', '', 'kickstart: version 7.1(4)N1(1)', '7.1(4)N1(1)')]

how to filter 7.0(3)I4(6) and 7.1(4)N1(1) based on the input

Comment: Try: `regex_version = re.compile(r'(NXOS:\sversion\s(\S+)|kickstart:\sversion\s(\S+))')` (the `|` must be in a group `()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regular expressions OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609597/python-regular-expressions-or)

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple with the `|` (OR) operator:

```
regex_version = re.compile(r'(NXOS:\sversion\s(\S+)|kickstart:\sversion\s(\S+))')
```

The key is that the OR operator goes between the two terms with no delimiting parentheses or brackets

Comment: tried that i am getting output as below                                                                  
[('NXOS: version 7.0(3)I4(6)', '7.0(3)I4(6)', '')]
[('kickstart: version 7.1(4)N1(1)', '', '7.1(4)N1(1)')]