# python run multiple lines on multiple regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a folder that need to contain certain files that contains magic in their name
so i have a list of all the files with os.listdir(sstable_dir_path) and i have a list of regexes that one of them supposed to match one of those filenames.
is there any way to do so without a nested for?

```
SSTABLE_FILENAMES_REGEXES = [re.compile(r'md-\d+-big-CompressionInfo.db'), re.compile(r'md-\d+-big-Data.db'),
                             re.compile(r'md-\d+-big-Digest.crc32'), re.compile(r'md-\d+-big-Filter.db'),
                             re.compile(r'md-\d+-big-Index.db'), re.compile(r'md-\d+-big-Statistics.db'),
                             re.compile(r'md-\d+-big-Summary.db'), re.compile(r'md-\d+-big-TOC.txt')]
```

filenames example:

```
md-146-big-CompressionInfo.db
md-146-big-Data.db
md-146-big-Digest.crc32
md-146-big-Filter.db
md-146-big-Index.db
md-146-big-Statistics.db
md-146-big-Summary.db
md-146-big-TOC.txt
```

how i currently do it

```
all([any([regex.fullmatch(fillename) for regex in SSTABLE_FILENAMES_REGEXES]) for fillename in os.listdir(sstable_dir_path)])
```

Comment: Hey you can use the operator OR in regex.

Comment: As @BenyGj noted, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609597/python-regular-expressions-or) then just use `re.compile` once on your single pattern with lots of `|` characters in it.

Comment: @KarlThornton what do you mean two sets of [] ?
using | does help thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to you could build a single regex in the format `(?=.*^pattern1$)(?=.*^pattern2$)` - the `(?=)` is a positive lookahead - the `^$` are used to emulate the "fullmatch" behaviour.

You can then create a multilined string from `os.listdir()` to match against.

```
SSTABLE_FILENAMES = [
    'big-CompressionInfo.db', 'big-Data.db', 'big-Digest.crc32', 'big-Filter.db',
    'big-Index.db', 'big-Statistics.db', 'big-Summary.db', 'big-TOC.txt'
]

regex = re.compile('(?ms)' + 
    ''.join(f'(?=.*^md-\d+-{re.escape(name)}$)' 
    for name in SSTABLE_FILENAMES)
)

>>> bool(regex.search('\n'.join(os.listdir(sstable_dir_path))))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
files = ['md-146-big-CompressionInfo.db', 
         'md-146-big-Data.db', 
         'md-146-big-Digest.crc32', 
         'md-146-big-Filter.db', 
         'md-146-big-Index.db', 
         'md-146-big-Statistics.db', 
         'md-146-big-Summary.db', 
         'md-146-big-TOC.txt']
pattern = '|'.join(map(lambda x: x.pattern, SSTABLE_FILENAMES_REGEXES))
res = [fillename for fillename in files.split() if re.fullmatch(pattern=pattern , string=fillename) ]

print(res)
```

result:

```
['md-146-big-CompressionInfo.db', 'md-146-big-Data.db', 'md-146-big-Digest.crc32', 'md-146-big-Filter.db', 'md-146-big-Index.db', 'md-146-big-Statistics.db', 'md-146-big-Summary.db', 'md-146-big-TOC.txt']
```

Comment: I want to know if i have a missing file and this way does not solve it but the overall idea does simplify it thanks

Comment: you can change the condition on the list comprehension.

Comment: Still wouldnt work because you iterate over filename so if a file in not there I wont know it