# How to search for 2 type in python regular expression

Tags: python

Actually i am trying to make a wifi interfaces grabber code in in ubuntu system.
my wifi interface name in iwconfig looks like this wlxa047d708ea27 when i turn this interface into monitor mode it changes into wlan0mon. my regular expression look like this `interfaces = re.compile(r'wlxa047d708ea[0-9]+')` which gives my real interface which is ok and i want to also include the re for wlan0mon in the above code. any help will be greatfull.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python regular expressions OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609597/python-regular-expressions-or)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.